# How to read multiple JSON docs in single JSON file using Java?

Tags: java, json

I am new on JSON, I want to read the JSON document using device id, I have many document on single file, just like as a database:

```
   {
      "deviceType":"AccessPoint",
      "transactionType":"response",
      "messageType":"set_config",
      "classes":[
          {
              "deviceType":"AccessPoint",
              "classId":1,
              "ipv4":"192.168.100.100",
              "netmask":"192.168.100.100",
              "ipv6":"192.168.100.100",
              "className":"Interface",
              "interfaceName":"wlan0",
              "state":"UP",
              "type":"wireless",
              "deviceId":"1234",
              "status":"waiting"
          }
       ],
     "deviceId":"1234",
     "transactionId":"201675"
   }
```

Sometimes, classes array contain multiple arrays like indexes [{},{},..].
So, how can I read the doc using search criteria with java web application.

Comment: Is this just a snippet or is it "valid" structure? The one you posted has 2 root elements and doesn't have comma separation in between (if they are elements of an array).

Comment: sanjay , do values inside classes repeat  or the entire structure repeats ?

Comment: inside classes values are repeat

Comment: You can use spring restcontroller....@RestController. This automatically will take care of conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of curiosity , did something on Jackson (streaming parser , since there is mention of large number of elements). I am just doing an output as name : value , this can be logically enhanced to suit your tastes. This is not even close to production , but is a good start.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("yourpath/transactions.json")) {
            JsonFactory jf = new JsonFactory();
            JsonParser jp = jf.createParser(fis);
            //System.out.println(JsonToken.START_ARRAY);
            // jp.setCodec(new ObjectMapper());
            jp.nextToken();
            while (jp.hasCurrentToken()) {

                if (jp.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.START_OBJECT)
                        || jp.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.START_ARRAY)
                        || jp.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.END_ARRAY)
                        || jp.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.END_OBJECT)) {
                } else {
                    System.out.print(jp.getText());
                    jp.nextToken();
                    System.out.print(":");
                    System.out.print(jp.getText());
                    System.out.println();
                }
                jp.nextToken();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```